# Fixing torch.cuda.is_available() when it is False

Tags: centos, pytorch, gpu, driver

How can I change the result of `torch.cuda.is_available()` to `True`?

These are some the information I can provide about my system:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  6 2019, 16:19:42) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.version.cuda
'8.0.61'
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
True
>>> torch.__version__
'1.0.0.dev20190328'
```

and

```
$ uname -a
Linux goku.bu.edu 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 15:27:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
Release:        7.8.2003
Codename:       Core


$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt 
CUDA Version 10.0.130

$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Sep 19 00:04:00 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   24C    P8    12W / 250W |     55MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   27C    P8    12W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2637      G   /usr/bin/X                         39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2903      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               12MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Regarding GPU:

```
$ lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 6598
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 88, NUMA node 0
        Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at fb000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 6598
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 89, NUMA node 0
        Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at f9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Pytorch hasn't launched official support for CUDA 11 yet. Although, you can try some of the solutions in this thread - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-with-cuda-11-compatibility/89254/4

Comment: @SVPraveen Nothing in this question indicates OP wants to use CUDA 11. The CUDA version indicated on nvidia-smi just indicates that the GPU drivers are up to date and support CUDA versions up to 11.0.

Comment: This is likely just an issue with how pytorch was installed. You're currently using pytorch 1.0.0. If you want to upgrade to the latest version then select the desired version of cuda and installation method (either pip or conda) from the quickstart table on [pytorch.org](http://pytorch.org) and use the indicated command. If you want to install older versions then you can use a command from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v100), just select the desired cuda and pytorch versions for your OS and installation method (you probably want to use cuda 10).